# Throat Lozenge and Hotza'a

Tags: halacha, shabbat, medicine, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot, eruv-chatzerot

What is the law of transfering between domains, and carrying outside with no eruv on Shabbat (*hotza'a*), with a [throat lozenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throat_lozenge) in one's mouth, when one has a sore throat?

Comment: Should be no better than Mishna Eruvin 10:5

Comment: See rashi there. Perhaps something that you’re swallowing isn’t included in that Mishnah. It should still be a problem because it’s the normal way to use it.

Comment: @Deuteronomy I don't know.